# Display dynamic editors in JSF with ui:include

Tags: java, jsf, include, primefaces, uiinclude

I want to display a group of editors in a tabview. Each editor has a property called *component*, that stores the rendered editor. Simple editors use HTML tags to render the editor, whereas complex ones use editors defined in another pages. I have found out that I cannot use `editor.component` with **ui:include** because the value is not available when the tree is build. How can I solve this issue? Are there any alternatives to ui:include that don't have this limitation?.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:panelGroup>
    <p:tabView value="#{groupsBean.groups}" var="group">  
        <p:tab title="#{group.name}">  
            <h:panelGroup>  
                <p:dataTable value="#{group.editors}" var="editor">  
                    <p:column headerText="Key">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{editor.name}" />  
                    </p:column>  
                    <p:column headerText="Value">
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not editor.href}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{editor.component}" escape="false" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{editor.href}">
                            <ui:include src="#{editor.component}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>  
                    </p:column>  
                </p:dataTable>  
            </h:panelGroup>  
        </p:tab>  
    </p:tabView>  
</h:panelGroup>
```

**EDIT 1**

**web.xml** contains these entries:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>  
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml; /WEB-INF/custom.taglib.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

**custom.taglib.xml** is inside WEB-INF folder.

```
<facelet-taglib>  
    <namespace>http://www.custom.ro/</namespace>  
    <tag>  
        <tag-name>dynamic</tag-name>  
        <component>  
            <component-type>ro.custom.DynamicInclude</component-type>                 
        </component>  
    </tag>  
</facelet-taglib>
```

DynamicInclude is annotated with `@FacesComponent("ro.custom.DynamicInclude")`

In **groups.xhtml** I have added the namespace for dynamic include - `xmlns:custom="http://www.custom.ro/"`.

**EDIT2**

Finally I have managed to make it work. The missing thing was the entry for handler-class(com.corejsf.tag.DynamicIncludeHandler). I have also removed the lines that tested the src for null in getSrc method of DynamicInclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such component alternative to ui:include. We have implemented such thing ourselves using FaceletContext.includeFacelet api.

A fairly simple alternative would be to render table using c:forEach loop - no need to code an extra component yourself. The drawback is you will get a component for each row which might be resource heavy in some cases.

Comment: Can you give me a small example of implementation with FaceletContext.includeFacelet api?

Comment: I haven't created a custom component before, this is my first time. I have added the two classes, created the tag library descriptor file with "dynamic" tag name and the component type attached(DynamicInclude), and added the tag library to javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES in web.xml. In the .xhtml file I use <custom:dynamic src="#{editor.component}" />, but nothing is displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try to make path as src start with application root, for example /WEB-INF/path/to/facelet. If it does not help, try debugger.

Comment: I have hardcoded #{editor.component} to /WEB-INF/editors/editor.xhtml.

Comment: I was looking at the page source with firebug and saw that <custom:dynamic src="/WEB-INF/editors/editor.xhtml"></custom:dynamic> tag exists.

Comment: If you see it under browser, it means tag was not handled properly.

Comment: <custom:dynamic src="/WEB-INF/editors/editor.xhtml"></custom:dynamic> is not displayed, but I can see it with firebug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9962/discussion-between-seitaridis-and-mrembisz)

Comment: I have added my current configuration for the custom component(EDIT1)

Comment: The application throws java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.corejsf.component.DynamicInclude.buildView(DynamicInclude.java:97) because faceletContext is null.

Comment: faceletContext is set in DynamicIncludeHandler, make sure it is registered properly.

Comment: I have fixed the issue with the modifications explained in EDIT2.